# SQL: How to condition the use of the greater than operator when comparing different columns

Tags: sql

To start, I have a query that pulls a lab id, a test code, and a result from a table...

```
SELECT WRID, WRTSTCDE, WRRSLT                          
FROM WTRESULT                                          
WHERE WRTSTCDE IN ('WC-COND', 'WC-TDS', 'WC-SO4SC')    
ORDER BY WRID
```

That yields some results like this...

```
  Test ID  ---------     Code    ---          RESULTS            
14,000,397   WC-COND               1      
14,000,408   WC-COND               683    
14,000,408   WC-SO4SC              329    
14,000,408   WC-TDS                444    
14,000,409   WC-COND               691    
14,000,409   WC-SO4SC              340    
14,000,409   WC-TDS                436
```

The results for WC-COND should always be greater than the results for WC-TDS.

The results for WC-TDS should always be greater than the results for WC-SO4SC.

We believe users have entered data erroneously into the database.

My question is this: what can I add to this query to make it show instances where WC-TDS are erroneously greater than WC-COND?  And similarly for WC-SO4SC if it is greater than WC-TDS?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use two queries, one for each wrstcde, and compare the results.

Something like so: (not tested)

```
select
t1.wrstcde,
t1.wtrslt,
t2.wrstcde,
t2.wtrslt
from
(
select
* from
wteresult
where
wrstcde = 'WC-COND' ) t1
join
(select
*
from
wrstcde = 'WC-SO4SC) t2
on t1.wrid = tw.wrid
where t2.WRRSLT > t1.wrrslt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case you need to pivot to give you the results in a simple to use format.

```
SELECT 
  t1.WRID, 
  CASE WHEN t1.WRTSTCDE = 'WC-COND'  THEN t1.WRRSLT ELSE NULL END as "WC-COND",
  CASE WHEN t2.WRTSTCDE = 'WC-TDS'   THEN t2.WRRSLT ELSE NULL END as "WC-TDS",
  CASE WHEN t3.WRTSTCDE = 'WC-SO4SC' THEN t3.WRRSLT ELSE NULL END as "WC-SO4SC",
FROM 
  WTRESULT t1
  INNER JOIN WTRESULT t2 on t1.WRID = t2.WRID
  INNER JOIN WTRESULT t3 on t1.WRID = t3.WRID
```

The above query will give you the results with lots of NULLs:

```
  Test ID    WC-COND   WC-TDS   WC-SO4SC    
14,000,397   <null>    <null>        1      
14,000,408   683       <null>   <null>
14,000,408   <null>    444      <null>
14,000,408   <null>    <null>      329   
14,000,409   691       <null>   <null>        
14,000,409   <null>    436      <null>        
14,000,409   <null>    <null>      340
```

(The actual result set might have even more NULLs since you have other values for WRTSTCDE. Additional WHERE clauses can exclude those, but they don't really hurt things.) Then to get what you really want, apply grouping:

```
SELECT 
  t1.WRID, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN t1.WRTSTCDE = 'WC-COND'  THEN t1.WRRSLT ELSE NULL END) as "WC-COND",
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.WRTSTCDE = 'WC-TDS'   THEN t2.WRRSLT ELSE NULL END) as "WC-TDS",
  MAX(CASE WHEN t3.WRTSTCDE = 'WC-SO4SC' THEN t3.WRRSLT ELSE NULL END) as "WC-SO4SC",
FROM 
  WTRESULT t1
  INNER JOIN WTRESULT t2 on t1.WRID = t2.WRID
  INNER JOIN WTRESULT t3 on t1.WRID = t3.WRID
GROUP BY t1.WRID
```

You end up with these simple results:

```
  Test ID    WC-COND   WC-TDS   WC-SO4SC    
14,000,397   <null>    <null>        1      
14,000,408   683       444         329
14,000,409   691       436         340
```

Applying your final filter becomes trivial once the data is in this form. Databases like Oracle and PostgreSQL have specialized syntax that could make the pivot easier. But this manual version should work most anywhere.